# manage login and logout in database codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, session

i am creating a chat module in that i have to show all the users who are currently online.
i am storing user information in ci_sessions table in codeigniter.
it works fine when user using normal login and logout process but it doesn't remove the user_data from ci_sessions table when user closes the application without clicking on logout.
so it remains logged in even if he is inactive.
how can i remove user_data whenever session expires and even if the user close the application without clicking on logout.

please help me.

thank you in advance.....

Comment: r u updating table or session when user logout

Comment: Yes my code destroys session and removes values from user_data column in ci_sessions table when click on Logout... but what if user doesn't click on logout and just close the application, it should update the values in database right?

Answer (score 1):

ok do one

1.)go to application folder then go to config.php then open it
2.)make $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE; it is default FALSE make it TRUE
3.)and also read doc for that..

also update the time $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300; to less

Comment: i have already set config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE and $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 120;

Comment: it destroyes the session but doesn't remove the value from user_data field in ci_sessions table if the user closes the application without using the logout button....